# How can I approve a PayPal payment in my specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am very new to PayPal API.

My rails server checks each payment if it is approved. I'm struggling with writing specs for it as I don't know how I can "fake" an approval.

I came up with 3 possibilities:

1. I don't check for approval in my specs.
2. I create a real sandbox payment and always use the `paymentId` of that payment.
3. I only test with implicit payments (which need no approval).

All 3 don't look very nice to me.

So the question remains: **How can I create an approved payment for my specs?**

Answer (score 2):

You should mock the response from the api. There is no need for you to actually do the request, but also no excuse for not testing your side of the code that handles the result of the api request. Assuming you want to mock the following code:

```
#controller.rb

def initialize(dependencies = {})
  @payment_service = dependencies.fetch(:paypal_api) do
    Payment
  end
end

...

def payment_method
  payment = @payment_service.find("PAY-57363176S1057143SKE2HO3A")

  if payment.execute(payer_id: "DUFRQ8GWYMJXC")
    # Do some stuff 
    return 'success!'
  end
  'failure!'
end
```

You could mock your response using something like this in Rspec:

```
# controller_spec.rb

let(:paypal_api) { double('Payment') } 
let(:mock_payment) { double('PayPal::SDK::REST::DataTypes::Payment') } 
let(:mock_controller) { described_class.new(paypal_api: paypal_api) }
...

it 'returns the correct result when the payment is successfull' do
  mock_response = {
     "paymentExecuteResponse":{
        "id":,
        "intent":"sale",
        "state":"approved",
        "cart":,
        "payer":{
           "payment_method":"paypal",
           "payer_info":{
              "email":,
              "first_name":,
              "last_name":,
              "payer_id":,
              "phone":,
              "country_code":
           }
        }
        ... some other stuff...
     }
  }

  ...
  # This mocks the find method from the sdk
  allow(paypal_api).to receive(:find).and_return(mock_payment)
  # This mocks the execution of the payment
  allow(mock_payment).to receive(:execute).and_return(mock_response)

  result = mock_controller.payment_method
  expect(result).to 'success!'
end
```

I also recommend taking a look at the [rspec docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/verifying-doubles) about doubles.

Comment: This is a nice answer. I'm struggling with `class_double(Payment)`: `uninitialized constant Payment`. Im including `PayPal::SDK::REST` within a module.

Comment: @Fabic If you are having trouble with the exact class names for the mocks, you can use regular `doubles` instead of `instance_doubles`.Instance / class doubles are better since they are closer to the real thing, but in this case it should be fine.
I'll update the example to use normal doubles.